# ios fast Image cache with server

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimage

I am trying to use [Path's FastImageCache library](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache#how-fast-image-cache-works) to handle photos in my app. The sample they provide simply reads the images from disk. Does anyone know how I might modify it to read from a url? In the section about [providing source images to the cache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache#providing-source-images-to-the-image-cache) they have

```
- (void)imageCache:(FICImageCache *)imageCache wantsSourceImageForEntity:(id<FICEntity>)entity withFormatName:(NSString *)formatName completionBlock:(FICImageRequestCompletionBlock)completionBlock {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Fetch the desired source image by making a network request
        NSURL *requestURL = [entity sourceImageURLWithFormatName:formatName];
        UIImage *sourceImage = [self _sourceImageForURL:requestURL];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(sourceImage);
        });
    });
}
```

Has anyone used this api before and know how to get the source from the server to pass to the cache? Another example that still uses hard disk is

```
- (void)imageCache:(FICImageCache *)imageCache wantsSourceImageForEntity:(id<FICEntity>)entity withFormatName:(NSString *)formatName completionBlock:(FICImageRequestCompletionBlock)completionBlock {
    // Images typically come from the Internet rather than from the app bundle directly, so this would be the place to fire off a network request to download the image.
    // For the purposes of this demo app, we'll just access images stored locally on disk.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *sourceImage = [(FICDPhoto *)entity sourceImage];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(sourceImage);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i suggest to use SDwebimage or AFN for image loading smooth and faster catch.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on Fast Image Cache while I was at Path. The critical portion of Fast Image Cache is that it is the absolute fastest way to go from image data on disk to being rendered by Core Animation. No decoding happens, none of the image data is kept in memory by your app, and no image copies occur.

That said, the responsibility is yours to figure out how to download the images. There's nothing inherently special about downloading images. You can use `NSURLConnection` or one of many popular networking libraries (like AFNetworking) to actually download the image data from your server. Once you have that image data, you can call the relevant completion block for Fast Image Cache to have it optimize it for future rendering.

If you're looking for a simple way to download an image and display it when it's finished, then use something like SDWebImage. It's great for simple cases like that. If you are running into performance bottlenecks—especially with scrolling—as a result of your app needing to display tons of images quickly, then Fast Image Cache is perfect for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Approach Seems a Lot Like Lazy Loading Images from the URL, I had to do this once I had Used the following Library to do it, It dosent stores the Images in the disk, but uses cached Images..the below is its link..
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Answer (score 0):

I added the networking logic to our fork > https://github.com/DZNS/FastImageCache#dezine-zync-additions-to-the-class

It utilizes NSURLSessionDownloadTasks, has a couple of configuration options (optional). All you need to do is create a new instance of `DZFICNetworkController` and set it as the delegate for FICImageCache's sharedCache instance object. It'll take care of downloading images with reference to the `sourceImageURLWithFormatName:` method on your objects conforming to `<FICEntity>`.

As I assume you'd use this in a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, calling `cancelImageRetrievalForEntity:withFormatName:` on the imageCache will cancel the download operation (if it's still in-flight or hasn't started).